# Does every function has a harmonic conjugate?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

In complex analysis , if $f(z)= u(x,y) + \iota v(x,y) $ is analytic,then v is called harmonic conjugate of u. If I try to find the harmonic conjugate of $u = x^2$ , I'm not getting any valid function  v.

1. Then what are the conditions for existence of harmonic function?
2. Which condition is violated , when I take the above $u$?

Comment: It helps is $u$ is harmonic: $x^2$ isn't.

Comment: You mean it has to satisfy Laplace equation?

Comment: $x^2$ isn't real part of an analytic function because, as Lord Shark said, it isn't harmonic.  "Harmonic" means it is $C^2$ and satisfies Laplace's equation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function

Comment: How silly of me! I just overlooked the definition itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author has found the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $u$ (defined on an open connected set $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C$) has a harmonic conjugate $v$ iff the function $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic on $\Omega.$ Consequently, if $u$ has a harmonic conjugate, then both are harmonic real-valued functions on $\Omega,$ meaning that they are twice continuously differentiable and satisfies the LaPlace equations $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}=0.$$

On the other hand, let's suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function on $\Omega.$ We'd like to show that there exists $f=u+iv$ such that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ and $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.$$ Now the LaPlace equations allow us to use line integrals to define $v$ locally as $$v=\int_C\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,dy\right).$$ By "locally," I mean that, given any point $z_0\in\Omega,$ there is some $r>0$ such that $z\in\Omega$ whenever $|z-z_0|<r,$ and for every such $z,$ we can define $v$ at $z$ by a line integral from $z_0$ to $z$ in this way. We may not be able to do better, because otherwise we can't guarantee independence of path, as we may have singularities throwing us off. However, what this *does* accomplish is proving that $v$ exists, though is only unique up to a constant term, so we've really only proved that a *family* of such functions $v$ exist, but that we don't necessarily have a canonical way to choose one.

Comment: What guarantees that v as you defined it is harmonic? Are you using the FThmCalculus?

Comment: To show that $v$ is a harmonic conjugate to $u$, one need only verify that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. The FTC is a nice way to do so.